# Matching currency with dollar signs ($) and commas (,) in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

In console of Firefox trying to find array using XPath:

```
<span class="ourPrice2">$99.99</span>
```

to do comparing it I used:

```
"//span[@class = 'ourPrice2' and number(substring(normalize-space(text()), 2)) >= 14.99]"
```

It helped, but what to do in situation like this:

```
<span class="bold">
                $63,995.00</span>

"//span[@class ='bold' and number(substring(normalize-space(text()), 2)) > '60,000.00']"
```

As far as I understand it doesn't work because "," . So what would be the solution?

Also , using of "number(substring(normalize-space(text()), 2))" I found this solution , I played with it and understand function "substring()" and "normalize-space()" but what "number()" for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use **[`number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number)** to convert a string to a number.  However, this is unnecessary since XPath will automatically do this for you.  Also, **[`number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number)** won't deal with dollar signs or commas, but you can eliminate the `$` and `,` characters using **[`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)**:

```
translate(normalize-space(), '$,', '')
```

So, your XPath then becomes:

```
//span[@class='bold' and translate(normalize-space(), '$,', '') > 60000]
```

and will select all of the (`@class='bold`) `span` elements with string values that can be translated into numbers less than 60000, as requested.

Comment: Thank you!  It helped! Could you please explain after ('$,') meaning of syntax (' ')?

Comment: XPath 1.0 has no specific function for deleting characters from a string, so the trick is to `translate()` the `$` and `,` characters to nothing `''` in order to remove them.